# ODOO 13 initiate input tag in widget

Tags: widget, odoo

**mytest.js**

```
odoo.define('base_phone_popup_mytest', function(require){
    "use strict";
    var core = require('web.core');
    var AbstractAction = require('web.AbstractAction');
    var mv = "";

    var Mytest = AbstractAction.extend({
//render your template
        template: "base.phone.popup.mytest",
        xmlDependencies: ['./base_phone_popup/static/src/xml/mytest.xml'],
//initialize
        init: function(parent) {
            var self = this;
            console.log(" mytest.js  ->  init " + arguments[1].context['myvalue']);
            mv = arguments[1].context['myvalue'];
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    },

//Binding Events
        events : {},
    });

    core.action_registry.add('base.phone.popup.mytest', Mytest);
    return {'mytest': Mytest};
});
```

**mytest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-name="base.phone.popup.mytest">
            <div class="o_mytest">
                <input type="text" id="id_mv" class="o_mv form-control" />
            </div>
    </t>
</templates>
```

some **template.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <template id="assets_backend" name="base_phone_popup assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/scss" href="/base_phone_popup/static/src/scss/mytest.scss"/>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/base_phone_popup/static/src/js/mytest.js"/>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

**mytest.scss**

```
.modal.o_technical_modal {
    .modal-content {
        border-radius: 0;
        width: 435px;
        height: 700px;
        }
}
.o_mytest {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 600px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background: #AFA;
    font-size: 64px;
}
.o_mv {
    height:66px;
    font-size:64px;strong text
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Question : Where and How can I place var mv to initial value for input o_mv ?

Myvalue is some asynch data from asterisk server in my case.

GetElementByID() not work until DOM loaded, bat work in event functions. Perhaps, i need modify

function render(), but I can't find working sample.

Answer (score 0):

I finded working sample.

```
start: function(parent) {
    var self = this;
    this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    self.$('.o_mv').val(mv);
```

},

This code set initial value mv to html page tag with class : o_mv. 
In my case this is :

```
<input type="text" id="id_mv" class="o_mv form-control" />
```